# Sage50 SData POST to tradingaccountCustomerfeed

Tags: c#, sage-erp, sdata

I am very new to Sage SDATA; so far I could read/write to various feeds using c#. I am trying to add phone number to tradingaccountCustomerfeed but failed. I could easily write to email, name, address fields etc. to this feed. 
I am not sure what am I missing, can anyone help? sample code could be extremely helpful.

Comment: Could you please specify your purpose, e.g. by providing a sample?

Comment: all details for sdata feed is on http://sage.github.io/SData-2.0/ try clicking on the Your comments? link they may be able to help you there